# The ultimate Vim/Tmux window renaming script

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm trying to achieve a consistent behavior when setting the tmux window name to the name of the current opened file in vim.

Here's what i have in my .vimrc

```
augroup tmux
  autocmd!
  if exists('$TMUX')
    autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost,BufNewFile,FocusGained * call system("tmux rename-window " . expand("%:t"))
    autocmd VimLeave,FocusLost * call system("tmux set-window-option automatic-rename")
  endif
augroup END
```

I've been facing two situational problems:

### Switching panes

This almost works. For jumping between panes, it renames every focus change but sometimes it fails and resets to default... I have no idea why.

### Switching windows

Same behavior as switching panes, sometimes it resets the name of the window you just left to default

I need to improve this script to behave like so:

- Switching panes renames current tmux window to filename (works poorly)
- Switching away from a window persists it's name
- Trunkate large filenames (is this even possible?)

I wonder if this has to do with my status bar refresh interval or some settings in my .tmux.conf so here it is
[my_tmuxconf](https://github.com/fabricio7p/RC-Files/blob/zsh-arch/.tmux.conf)

Here are some gifs on the wierd behavior:
[switching windows](https://media.giphy.com/media/RLuJPDDRTiJxRBdxLE/giphy.gif)
[switching panes](https://media.giphy.com/media/L0kXjwdi4YhI1VmMG2/giphy.gif)

## Update

This implementation gives better results:

```
if exists('$TMUX')
  autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained * call system("tmux rename-window " . expand("%:t"))
  autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux rename-window zsh")
endif
```

But the drawback is that it can't rename when you switch from a pane running vim to a pane running something else eg, regular bash.

The missing piece is to make Tmux autorename on every pane switch, but only if the focused pane is not running vim. Can it be done?

Comment: For switching panes, you have a race condition. There is no guarantee that the previous vim pane will trigger its commands before the next vim pane does, meaning sometimes you will get the name set to the new file and *then* get reset to the default name. This is not a problem vim can solve. Vim has tabs and buffers if you want a solution that is vim native.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the cleanup function? Do you have any workaround ideas for like checking if it's a pane switch and don't clean up the previous filename?

Comment: I don't. The vim instance you are leaving cannot know where you are going, or what terminal emulator its in, or what its system calls do. It is just doing the command you told it to do when you leave.

Comment: Please check my update. I think this would work if with an extra tmux script